# Track users moving folders on shared network drive?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have users moving project folders from one area to another which they should not be doing.  How can I find out on the server who's moved a file or folder?  Is there a built in Windows Server 2003 function??

Answer (score 1):

Turn on audit policy in Active Directory.

Here's a quick howto:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814595